# Copy email when left clicking it

Tags: google-chrome, ubuntu-20.04

In chrome is it possible to copy an email address when left clicking it? (Something like setting chrome://settings/handlers but to a program that just copies the link to the clipboard.)

---

Chrome on Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Firefox; Right click on top of the email (mailto link), select "copy email address" - or are you lazier than so? ;-)

Comment: @Hannu, I am indeed lazier ;) since there is build in functionality to do something with an email address (such as open an in my opinion always annoying email client) it should be possible to perform the simpler task of simply copying the address to the clipboard.

Comment: I'm probably talking to the empty air but an explanation for the down-vote would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

On linux you have a seperate clipboard to the usual <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> & <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> clipboard, called the [primary selection](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/139191/whats-the-difference-between-primary-selection-and-clipboard-buffer).

You can use it by simply selecting/marking text with your mouse. To paste the text press your middle mouse button. Note that this not only works with email addresses but with all text.

Comment: Thanks. Perhaps helpful for some. I work on a touchpad without reliable middle mouse button and have disabled the mid-click copy. I'm looking for something like chrome://settings/handlers to change the specific action of left clicking an email address.